# How to Manually Adjust Value of timestamp To Previous Year?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using timestamp to store the pubdate of uploads. I want to add a filter to sort records by the year they were uploaded so need to change a couple of records to previous years for testing purposes. When I try to manually adjust the date from within mysql by clicking the calendar and picking a date it flags errors.

The value of timestamp is set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
The values of function in the timestamp field are :

```
NOW
CURDATE
FROM_DAYS
FROM_UNIXTIME
PERIOD_ADD
PERIOD_DIFF
TO_DAYS
```

I cannot find anything online relating to this. I don't need to perform calculations I need to manually adjust the date.

Comment: did you use the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` option upon creating your table? This would cause mysql to update the timestamp each time you update th row, thus you cannot update the timestamp as it would be more or less overwritten.

Comment: No. I'm not familiar with it. My field is named pubdate so how would I use the ON UPDATE function to change the value of a field to '2013-10-27 00:00:00',?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the problem is that you used an `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on this column you can remove this setting by redefining your column:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable MODIFY COLUMN pubdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

You might also check the docs:

```
With neither DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP nor ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
it is the same as specifying both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
```

And I guess your table was created without defining any of those two resulting in the behavior that you cannot update this column as it is updated automatically.
What happens is:

1. You pick a row and overwrite the timestamp (like setting the date to 2013)
2. MySQL detects that the row was updated
3. as `ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP` is implicitly specified MySQL updates the timestamp field with the current timestamp
4. Your changes to the timestamp will be overwritten / lost

Comment: No. The current date is being recorded that is not the issue. The value of the column is current_timestamp. I need to enter dates from 2013 and 2012 in order to test a date filter.

Comment: I know but this statement would remove any `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` settings which would prevent you from changing the timestamps

Comment: Oh right. Thanks. I have changed some entries. Do I repeat that statement to enforce current_timestamp for new entries?

Comment: No this statements alters the TABLE and does not only affect certain rows in your table. Therefore the issue is solved permanently. In case you want to undo this change you can use another alter table (actually same statement above) and append `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to the query.